# Computing a double integral using MATLAB

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals, matlab

I need to compute a double integral using MATLAB
I'm not good at programming.
I believe you just have to use this function called integral2
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html
But I'm not sure how to use it, even after searching up for examples online. I don't know how to define the function.

I'm using this site to run the MATLAB.
http://www.compileonline.com/execute_matlab_online.php

[image]

Comment: Please don't post questions both on MSE and MO at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The site that you are using uses free analogue of Matlab: GNU Octave.
There you can use function dblquad http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dblquad.html.

`dblquad(@(x, y) exp(x.**2 .* sin(y)), -1, 1, -1, 1)`